# Google Distance Matrix API issue (non-English input, latlng input doesn't seem to work)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-distancematrix-api, google-places-autocomplete

I got address from Google Autocomplete function, and when I put the address into Google Distance Matrix API (calling in the browser), I get No_Results.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=대한민국%20서울특별시%20강남구%20코엑스&destinations=대한민국%20강원도%20평창군%20대관령면%20용산리%20용평리조트&key=](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%20%EC%84%9C%EC%9A%B8%ED%8A%B9%EB%B3%84%EC%8B%9C%20%EA%B0%95%EB%82%A8%EA%B5%AC%20%EC%BD%94%EC%97%91%EC%8A%A4&destinations=%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%20%EA%B0%95%EC%9B%90%EB%8F%84%20%ED%8F%89%EC%B0%BD%EA%B5%B0%20%EB%8C%80%EA%B4%80%EB%A0%B9%EB%A9%B4%20%EC%9A%A9%EC%82%B0%EB%A6%AC%20%EC%9A%A9%ED%8F%89%EB%A6%AC%EC%A1%B0%ED%8A%B8&key=)

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "대한민국 강원도 평창군 대관령면 130" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "대한민국 서울특별시 강남구 삼성1동 영동대로 513" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm not sure whether it because 
   1) Input addresses are in Korean and are in Korea region => when I input "Washington,DC", and "New York,NY", I get valid results

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "미국 뉴욕" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "미국 워싱턴 DC 워싱턴" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "362 km",
                  "value" : 361940
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3시간 51분",
                  "value" : 13842
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

2) Lat, lng coordinates works better with Google Distance Matrix API than addresses => but thn when I put lat, lng coordinates of the same Korean addresses, it doesn't work either.  I got the lat, lng coordinates from Google autocomplete

```
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
 autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var placeGeo = place.geometry.location;


{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get ZERO_RESULTS is because for default your query is in "mode=driving", and  driving/walking/cycling directions are not supported in South Korea.

https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage

The only mode supported right now in SK is mode=transit, if you subtitude your query for:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=대한민국%20서울특별시%20강남구%20코엑스&destinations=대한민국%20강원도%20평창군%20대관령면%20용산리%20용평리조트&mode=transit&key=](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%20%EC%84%9C%EC%9A%B8%ED%8A%B9%EB%B3%84%EC%8B%9C%20%EA%B0%95%EB%82%A8%EA%B5%AC%20%EC%BD%94%EC%97%91%EC%8A%A4&destinations=%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%20%EA%B0%95%EC%9B%90%EB%8F%84%20%ED%8F%89%EC%B0%BD%EA%B5%B0%20%EB%8C%80%EA%B4%80%EB%A0%B9%EB%A9%B4%20%EC%9A%A9%EC%82%B0%EB%A6%AC%20%EC%9A%A9%ED%8F%89%EB%A6%AC%EC%A1%B0%ED%8A%B8&mode=transit&key=)

You should see a success responde like:

```
{

  destination_addresses: [

     "130 Daegwalnyeong-myeon, Pyeongchang-gun, Gangwon-do, South Korea"

  ],
  origin_addresses: [

     "513 Yeongdong-daero, Samseong 1(il)-dong, Gangnam-gu, Seoul, South Korea"

  ],

  rows: [
    {
        elements: [
          {
            distance: {
                 text: "158 km",
                 value: 157837
            },
            duration: {
                 text: "12 hours 4 mins",
                 value: 43446
                 },
                 status: "OK"
          }
         ]
     }
],
status: "OK"
}
```